# Way to remove "Recent Accounts" "Tools", and "Reports"

Tags: apex, visualforce, account, configuration

Is there any internal way to remove tile boxes of "Recent Accounts", "Tools", and "Reports" on the Accounts Landing page.

Any internal configuration which can let this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple Visualforce page using the Standard Set Controller and the enhancedList component, and then override the "Accounts Tab" page with your custom Visualforce. This override is done in Setup -> Customize -> Accounts -> Buttons, Links, and Actions.